Flutter run issue
ethanchristmas@Ethans-Air-3 ethans_detection2 % flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/ethanchristmas/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/ethanchristmas/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d9e926982c2c139ff9125eb7b6be4144/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/ethanchristmas/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d9e926982c2c139ff9125eb7b6be4144/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             20.3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I am not sure what to try. I was expecting my app to open in the android emulator.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
